# How to print value of a hash map according to increasing/decreasing order of key in c++?

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap

If we have a map,

```
map <int,int> m;
```

and following key value pair (-2,3) , (-14,8) , (4,8), (6,12) , (3,76)

Now if we want to print value in increasing order of keys,then how to print ?

o/p

8 3 76 8 12

Comment: The standard library `map` is not a hash map, it is a binary search tree. `unordered_map` is a hash map.

Comment: If you meant to show `unordered_map` in your code, then an answer is to copy the keys to a `vector`, `std::sort` it, then iterate over the `vector` of keys performing lookups in the `unordered_map` to print values.  Sounds tedious, but it's only three or four lines of simple code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys in a `std::map` are ordered by default (using `operator<`). You can just iterate over the map:

```
for (std::map<int, int>::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)
{
    cout << i->second << "\n";
}
```